# Replacing single quotes in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to take a string like this:

```
B R2 U2 B F U2 L2 F2 U2 R2 F' U' B' D R' U2 B U' R B F'
```

and display it in HTML as a title on a span so when you hover over the span, that string shows up as it's hover text.

I'm trying to take those single quotes (') and escape them so they can still show up in the string but don't end the title attribute early, which is what it does right now.

If I try this:

```
var fixedString = string.replace("'", "\'");
col.innerHTML = "<span title='" + fixedString + "'>" + irrelevantVar + "</span>";
```

This displays the string up until the first single quote and then it stops. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regex in your .replace() function and add a global flag

```
var fixedString = string.replace(/'/g, "\'");
```

The "g" flag tells that the regex should be tested in all occurrences in the string provided. Without the flag, it will only run once on the first match.

Reference: [Regular Expression on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters)

---

By the way aside from replacing and escaping, you can show the quote using the "apos" html code. See here for the reference: [W3 HTML Entities](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography)

Comment: Just using the "\'" didn't work, but replacing that with &apos; did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.replace(subString, replaceVal)` will only ever replace the first substring it finds [MOZ Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). If you want to replace all occurrences you will need to make the first argument a Regular Expression. I have modified your snippet with the appropriate expression. `//` denotes a Regex, and the `g` tag after means it will look for all occurrences of the string (or expression) within the `//`.

```
var fixedString = string.replace(/'/g, "\'");
col.innerHTML = "<span title='" + fixedString + "'>" + irrelevantVar + "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template literals` instead of putting the title value again inside a single quote

```js
let string = "B R2 U2 B F U2 L2 F2 U2 R2 F' U' B' D R' U2 B U' R B F'"
let col = document.getElementById('test')



var fixedString = string.replace("'", "\'");
col.innerHTML = `<span title="${fixedString}">Hello</span>`;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```